# Azure function not working on https, only http

Tags: azure, function, https

I created a new function app and function and i can not reach hit the function URL via HTTPS (simple GET in the browser - Site can't be reached error), but the HTTP version works.

Is there something i need to configure for HTTPS to actually work or is there a lag time? I have been through all the options and compared with another function app that does work via https and can see no difference in the settings. If i set the SSL > "Https only" setting to true, it still does not work; all this does is remove the http endpoint that does.

Anyone experienced this before?

Comment: if this answer would be helpful for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42403492/azure-functions-force-https

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone wondering - there was a lag time. It worked the following day.

Comment: Im experiencing this issure right now, hope it works eventually. Maybe 30 mins since first deployment